# Запрос из внешней программы (1С)

Tags: xml, 1с

При запросе в браузере Chrome (например поиск города Грац в Австрии)
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Грац%20Австрия&language=ru
возвращает XML файл в **русскими** названиями.

При запросе из 1С формируется точно такой же адрес
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Грац%20Австрия&language=ru
но возвращает XML файл в **НЕрусскими** названиями.
Grazstraße, Premstätten и т.д.

Почему?

Comment: А как именно вы формируете запрос из 1С? О какой версии платформы идёт речь?

Comment: Посмотри Фиддлером все заголовки отбправляемые браузером и вставь их в свой запрос

Answer (score 0):

Привожу рабочий код

```
Адрес = "maps.googleapis.com";
Соединение  =  Новый HTTPСоединение(Адрес);
ПолучениеЗапрос = "maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%20%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F&language=ru";
Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос(ПолучениеЗапрос);
Ответ = Соединение.Получить(Запрос);
ЧтениеХМЛ = Новый ЧтениеXML;
ЧтениеХМЛ.УстановитьСтроку(Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакСтроку());
ТвойФайл = ФабрикаXDTO.ПрочитатьXML(ЧтениеХМЛ);
```

[image: Скриншот полученного рещультата]